# CoreBluetooth not available in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, dynamic-tables

I implemented a class for sending a message out to a peripheral.
This class should be called when in a dynamic table a switch is turned on.

Problem is now, that in the UITableViewCell class CoreBluetooth is not supported.
I can create a object of my connection class but I can't fill out the attributes caused by missing support of CoreBluetooth.

Do you have an idea how I can realize the calls of the methods when the switch is tapped. Maybe I should catch the tap at an other part of my app.

**Here is my code of the Class with type of UITableViewCell**

```
import UIKit


class remoteCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var remoteCellLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var remoteCellImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var remoteCellSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var remoteCellPower: UIProgressView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    //HERE I CAN CATCH THE SWITCH TAP BUT I CAN'T USE CoreBluetooh IN THIS CLASS
    @IBAction func onOff(sender: AnyObject) {


        //OBJECT FROM THE CLASS FOR CONNECT AND SEND TO THE PERIPHERAL
        var connection: ViewController = ViewController()

        connection.viewDidLoad()


        //CANT FILLOUT THE ATTRIBUTES BECAUSE OF MISSING COREBLUETOOTH SUPPORT
    //-->        
        connection.centralManagerDidUpdateState(<#T##central: CBCentralManager##CBCentralManager#>)
        connection.centralManager(<#T##central: CBCentralManager##CBCentralManager#>, didDiscoverPeripheral: <#T##CBPeripheral#>, advertisementData: <#T##[String : AnyObject]#>, RSSI: <#T##NSNumber#>)
        connection.centralManager(<#T##central: CBCentralManager##CBCentralManager#>, didConnectPeripheral: <#T##CBPeripheral#>)
        connection.centralManager(<#T##central: CBCentralManager##CBCentralManager#>, didDiscoverPeripheral: <#T##CBPeripheral#>, advertisementData: <#T##[String : AnyObject]#>, RSSI: <#T##NSNumber#>)
        connection.centralManager(<#T##central: CBCentralManager##CBCentralManager#>, didConnectPeripheral: <#T##CBPeripheral#>)
        connection.peripheral(<#T##peripheral: CBPeripheral##CBPeripheral#>, didDiscoverServices: <#T##NSError?#>)
        connection.peripheral(<#T##peripheral: CBPeripheral##CBPeripheral#>, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService: <#T##CBService#>, error: <#T##NSError?#>)
        connection.peripheral(<#T##peripheral: CBPeripheral##CBPeripheral#>, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic: <#T##CBCharacteristic#>, error: <#T##NSError?#>)
        connection.peripheral(<#T##peripheral: CBPeripheral##CBPeripheral#>, didWriteValueForDescriptor: <#T##CBDescriptor#>, error: <#T##NSError?#>)

    //->
    }
    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    }
```

You see the Methods are the usual CoreBluetooth methods.

Is there a way to use these Methods in this class or where can I put my bluetooth logical behind a SwitchTap gesture when the Switch is in a dynamic table?

Thank you

René

Comment: You forgot to `import CoreBluetooth`.

Comment: It doesn't work so CoreBluetooth Import is not an option

`import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth


class remoteCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate{`

There is a crash does not conform to Protocol CBCentralManagerDelegate ....

Comment: Separate your CoreBluetooth methods from your custom UITableviewCells - keep them apart and only share the text data or whatever you get from your Bluetooth code with your cells. If you're getting a crash from the Bluetooth delegate, implement those delegate methods (they may be required the way UITableView methods like numberOfRows are required).

Comment: @JohnnyRockex
I tried that but how can I jump from one controller to an other and back?
I know how to do that via Segues but my connection should be done in the Background and don't have a own view. The view should stay when the switch is turned on, only the logical for the connection should run in the background.

Comment: If I were you, I would have a class left exclusively for Bluetooth functions, you connect in this class, receive data from this class etc. Make sure this runs fine, including all the delegate calls etc. This would most likely be a subclass of NSObject. Then, you have a separate subclass of UIViewController - this is where you can build your UI (e.g. linking with other subclasses) and query the data from your Bluetooth class (or better, have it update this). You would never 'segue' into the Bluetooth class because it's not for your UI, it's for data. Check out 'MVC' for more info.

Comment: Import e.g. "BluetoothObject.h" in your ViewController class, and ask it to start looking for BLE devices or whatever. When it finds something, it can call your ViewController class e.g. via a notification. If you need specific code for this let me know.